# AngularJS Directives - why do I need to call $compile in link() for expression defined in compile()?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this code:

```
app.directive('foo', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    template: '<span>{{bar}}</span>',
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      element.attr('title', '{{bar}}');
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.bar = 'hello';
        $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nFTgvYqoiFAthmjoizWS?p=preview

If I remove the `$compile` bit in the link function then the title attribute remains with the expression text (`{{bar}}`) and not the value (`'hello'`);

Anyone can explain why?

I thought (from what I read in the docs) that this is what the compile phase is for - manipulating the template and preparing it for the link with scope and data binding. Why do I need to manually call `$compile` again? Isn't the template already compiled?

Comment: Maybe the phase names should be changed from `compile`, `preLink`, and `postLink` to `postCompile`, `preLink`, and `postLink` The postCompile phase is availble to manipulate DOM before linking to a scope, at this point the linking function has been created but no scopes have  been created. DOM can be added that requires no compilation. If additional elements are added that include directives or require interpolation, those additional elements need to be compiled and linked in order for the directives and interpolation to work.

Comment: To manupulate the template before compile, furnish a function to the `template` property: `template: function(tElement, tAttrs) {}`. For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference -- Template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-template-).

Comment: @georgeawg Thanks! Can you point me to a reference where I could've read it myself? I'm wondering how I should've known about this (and how do you know about it :))

Comment: @georgeawg You can add it to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the phase names should be changed from `compile`, `preLink`, and `postLink` to `postCompile`, `preLink`, and `postLink`. The `postCompile` phase is availble to manipulate DOM before linking to a scope, at this point the linking function has been created but no scopes have been created. DOM can be added that requires no compilation. If additional elements are added that include directives or require interpolation, those additional elements need to be compiled and linked in order for the directives and interpolation to work.

To manupulate the template before compile, furnish a function to the template property: `template: function(tElement, tAttrs) {}`. For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference -- Template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#-template-).

---

> can you share a reference to "DOM can be added that requires no compilation, etc." or explain how did you found out about this?

Some sources of information:

- [AngularJS Developers Guide -- HTML Compiler](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler)
- [AngularJS Developers Guide -- Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom)

Comment: Please, can you share a reference to "DOM can be added that requires no compilation, etc." or explain how did you found out about this? I really wish to understand this properly and save myself future digging.